# sorting elements in a javascript multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Doing some work in javascript
I have a multidimensional made up in this format ( I know it’s not an actually array object, bit it gives you an idea of the format

```
[
  [[“ip-address”][timestamp]],
  [[“ip-address”][timestamp]],
  [[“ip-address”][timestamp]],
  [[“ip-address”][timestamp]]
]
```

The array can include duplicate ip addresses and I need a way to first sort the array by timestamps and then echo out the first instance of the ip address (i.e. for each ip address I need the one with the earliest timestamp)

For example

```
[[“10.0.0.1”][13:01:34]]
[[“10.0.0.1”][ 13:21:56]]
[[“192.168.1.1”][23:45:12]]
[[“192.168.1.1”][12:34:42]]
```

Would give me the following output

```
10.0.0.1 = 13:01:34
192.168.1.1 = 12:34:42
```

I’ve had a hunt around and can’t see a way to do this so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
result=[];
$.each(source,function(ip,timestamp)
{
    if( result[ip]==undefined || timestamp < result[ip] )
    {
        result[ip]=timestamp;
    }
});
```

Comment: that looks perfect, I'll have a play tomorrow when I'm back at my computer but I'm sure it's just the thing I need